# Performant WHERE Clause for Large Table Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

Table `Alpha` has 30,000 rows, and table `Beta` has 3 million rows. `Beta` also has a foreign key, `AlphaId`, that relates to `Alpha`'s PK.

I have a stored procedure in SQL-Server, that takes `@alphaId` as a param. Currently, my code runs

```
SELECT Alpha.Id, Alpha.Field1, Alpha.Field2, Beta.Field3, Beta.Field4
FROM
     Alpha
     INNER JOIN Beta ON Alpha.Id = Beta.AlphaId
WHERE
     Alpha.Id = @alphaId
```

The stored procedure is a bit slow. Would it speed up if I changed the `WHERE` clause to instead filter against `Beta`?

```
WHERE
     Beta.AlphaId = @alphaId
```

Would there be any value to having the `WHERE` clause compare against **both** `Alpha` and `Beta` tables?

```
WHERE
     Alpha.Id = @alphaId
     AND Beta.AlphaId = @alphaId
```

Comment: Do you have an index on `Beta (alphaID)` ?

Comment: I do have an index on Beta (alphaID).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. what execution plan says, does it uses indexes?
2. how many rows usually returned from this stored procedure?
3. a bit slow - how long it takes right now and how long it will be "not slow"?

answer to questions in topic:

**"Would it speed up if I changed the WHERE clause to instead filter against Beta?"**

No

**"Would there be any value to having the WHERE clause compare against BOTH Alpha and Beta tables?"**

No

The reason for both is the same - ms sql will do absolutely the same comparisons in all 3 cases

Comment: Alpha.Id is a unique clustered index. Beta.AlphaId has a non-unique, non-clustered index. It returns between 15 and 300 rows.

Comment: and what about execution plan?

Comment: In SSMS, it can take 2 seconds to run. (The ACTUAL stored proc joins in several tables; I'm just simplifying an issue to a theorized solution.) "Not slow" would be an IMMEDIATE resultset (always 0s). The web site that calls the proc occasionally times-out.

Comment: read [execution plan](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071(v=sql.105).aspx) and then I suppose you will find answer to your real question, or you can update topic here with full proper data to analyse

Answer (score 0):

If your database system is any good, those three queries will result in the same query plan and hence the same performance.

I'd try to index the database so that the query can be answered from the index:

```
create index alpha_i on alpha (Id, Field1, Field2)
create index beta_i on beta (alphaId, Field3, Field4)
```

Since indexes are usually cached in RAM, in the best case, the database won't even have to hit the hard disk to answer the query.